# getting knockout working with asp.net master page

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I'm just trying to get a knockout bound drop down working with asp.net master page. In the master page, I have the script references to jquery and knockout. In a sample content page, I have the following, but the select control never gets populated. What am I missing?

```
<asp:content id="Content1" contentplaceholderid="contentBody" runat="server">

    <select data-bind="options: docTypes ,
        optionsCaption: 'Choose document type',
        optionsText: 'name',
        value: chosenDocType"></select>
<script>
    $(function(){
        function emailViewModel() {
            this.docTypes = [
                { name: "1" },
                { name: "2" },
                { name: "3" }
            ];
            this.chosenDocType = ko.observable();
        }
        ko.applyBindings(emailViewModel);
    });
</script>
</asp:content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not instantiating the emailViewModel

Change

```
ko.applyBindings(emailViewModel);
```

to this

```
ko.applyBindings(new emailViewModel());
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/heads5150/mJsUp/)

Comment: thanks, but same result. Even in your fiddle I don't see anything in the dropdown (firefox 18)

Comment: Works for me in Firefox 18 outside of jsfiddle. Maybe there's an issue with jsfiddle and firefox 18